# How to resolve a 'Cannot set property "pages" of the undefined' error in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to define the visibility of certain items based on the userType in TypeScript that has logged in. However when I am trying to define the pages, I get a run time error that cannot set property pages of the undefined.
Kindly help me please.

My code:

```
    export class MenuPage implements OnInit {
      pages : [];
      value="";

      definepages(){ 
        var pages=[];
        var usersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Users');
        var userEmail = "";
        var userType = "";
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
          if (user) {
            console.log(user.email);
            userEmail = user.email;
            //userType = user.userType;
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
          }
        });

        var counter = 0;
        var currentUserData = {};
        usersRef.once("value", function (snapshot) {
          pages=[];
          snapshot.forEach(function (c) {
            if (userEmail == c.val().email) {
              currentUserData["email"] = userEmail;
              currentUserData["entity"] = c.val().userType;
              if( currentUserData["entity"]== 'Admin')
              {

               this.pages = [
              {
                title:'Home',
                url:'/menu/home',
                display:'false',
                icon:'home'
              },
              {
                title:'Register',
                url:'/menu/register',
                display:'true',
                icon:'create'
              },
              {
                title:'Login',
                url:'/menu/login',
                display:'true',
                icon:'log-in'
              },
              {
                title:'Shop by Brand',
                url:'/menu/brand',
                display:'true',
                icon:'log-in'
              },
              {
                title:'Shop by Category',
                url:'/menu/category',
                display:'true',
                icon:'log-in'
              },
            ];
            }
            else if(currentUserData["entity"]== 'Sakhi')
            {
              this.pages=[
                {
                  title:'My Inventory',
                  url:'/menu/my-inventory',
                  display:'true',
                  icon:'log-in'
                },
                {
                  title:'Contact-Us',
                  url:'/menu/contact',
                  display:'true',
                  icon:'contacts'
                },
              ];
              console.log("hello");
            }     
            }//check user email details

          });

        }
        );
      }
      constructor() { this.pages=[]}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.definepages();
      }

    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pages' of undefined
>       at menu.page.ts:40.

Answer (score 0):

You have these lines under the function scope `pages=[];` which is mostly giving you error, you probably wanted to replace with this.pages. And I see you are also creating `var pages` local variable, not sure if you need that, can be replaced with `this.pages = []`.